# $L_\infty[0;1] \subset L_1[0;1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Is it true that $L_\infty[0;1] \subset L_1[0;1]$ ? How can I prove it?

If $f \in L_\infty[0;1]$, then it's essentially bounded, then we can change $f$ on a zero-measure set and get a bounded on $[0;1]$ function  which must be Lebesgue-integrable? Is it true?

Comment: This is just one line with the triangle inequality: for any measure $\mu$, $\int_X |f| \, d\mu \le \|f\|_{\infty} \mu(X)$.

Comment: Okay, so I trivially get what I need